# I can't install any application because of "Problem with Mergelist"

Tags: apt

How can I solve the problem below?

```
$ sudo apt-get install gtypist
sudo: unable to resolve host vanz
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_noobslab_malys-themes_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: This is the same thing I had previously answered but now have sufficient reputation to comment.
It says that it is unable to resolve the host. Have you modified your /etc/hosts file and, in doing so, removed/commented out the default line that should look something like `127.0.0.1  vanz`. Even if you haven't intentionally, can you please confirm this exists so we can rule out that something else hasn't modified it?

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the PPA with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

(See [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed#310))

Or edit the file and comment out everything there. Later you can remove it if this fixes the problem.